# Speed of a PRNG

Tags: random

Is there a specific algorithm or method of calculating the speed of a pseudo random number generator?
I've recently made a PRNG, and for my last question here I learned that the Big-O analysis is not suitable in my situation.
I want to compare my program's speed to a well known pseudo random number generator, but I can't find any valuable information related to it.

Comment: Either do a mathematical analysis of run-time (the Big-O that you want to avoid) or benchmark specific implementations. This question is too broad. You seem to be asking how to compare the run-times of two algorithms (the fact that the algorithms are PRNGs doesn't seem all that relevant). Also, note that *run time* is seldom a decisive consideration in PRNGs. Statistical distribution and/or cryptographical security is much more important.

Comment: @JohnColeman Big-O is about how a problem scales, not how fast it is, so that won't help here.  That leaves benchmarking, which is heavily dependent on the OS, the language, the compiler, the hardware, and the skill of the implementer.  I have to disagree about run time not being an important consideration.  Distribution and/or crypto security comes first, but Monte Carlo models go through random numbers like a drunk goes through salted peanuts so if two or more generators meet quality requirements, speed can be a tie-breaker.

Comment: @pjs Good point about Big-O. I don't disagree that speed is important. OP has developed a custom PRNG. Like custom crypto, this is easy enough to do but hard to do *well*. If they haven't analyzed the statistical (or cryptographical, if relevant) quality then their concerns about speed are possibly premature.

Comment: @JohnColeman Totally agree with you!  Quality is paramount, building a good generator is far harder than most people realize.

Comment: The diehard/dieharder tests for testing the quality of a PRNG also measure time. Adding one to the suite isn't difficult.